# Google Tag Manager LookUp of LookUps Output Values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have grouped four sets of landing pages into four corresponding LookUp Table variables, using {{page path}} as the input variable. I've applied an output value for each landing page within each of these groupings.

I group the above variables into another LookUp Table variable (basically a LookUp of LookUps), and use this in an all-pages pageview tag to populate a Google Universal Content Grouping.

My question is whether I need to apply an output value to each input in the LookUp of LookUps?

Asked differently -- since output values are applied to each input in the four landing page lookups, will these pass through to the lookup of lookups, or do I need to apply output values there, too?

Comment: I don't know but I would say try it out and let us know the results. :)

Answer (score 0):

In short, the approach above cannot work. It requires GTM variable values to change (as values go from the set of lookups to the 'lookup of lookups'), but they're not meant to chance. A variable is meant to either represent a value, or not.

I wound up inserting dataLayer variables into the landing page code to apply the needed page-by-page designations.